# Why Node.js failed to serve .woff files

Tags: node.js, http, nginx

I downloaded the `.woff` file from Google web fonts for some network reason in China. Previously I tried `@font-face` that on [Github Pages](http://jiyinyiyong.github.com/she/bin/) and it works. But this time it took me an hour to find where was broken.

I use Node to serve static files with `mime`, and the `content-type` appears to be `application/x-font-woff`, and my code in CoffeeScript:

```
exports.read = (url, res) ->
  filepath = path.join __dirname, '../', url
  if fs.existsSync filepath
    file_content = fs.readFileSync filepath, 'utf8'
    show (mime.lookup url)
    res.writeHead 200, 'content-type': (mime.lookup url)
    res.end file_content
  else
    res.writeHead 404
    res.end()
```

As the `content-type` of `.woff` on Github Pages is `application/octet-stream`, I just commnet out that line in my code to make it the same.. But it still failed:

```
exports.read = (url, res) ->
  filepath = path.join __dirname, '../', url
  if fs.existsSync filepath
    file_content = fs.readFileSync filepath, 'utf8'
    show (mime.lookup url)
    # res.writeHead 200, 'content-type': (mime.lookup url)
    res.end file_content
  else
    res.writeHead 404
    res.end()
```

At last, I switched to a Nginx server to serve the `.woff` file.. and finally it began to work.

But how Can I fix that on Node?

Comment: Actually, serving files with nginx is generally a much better idea. Why do you want to do it on node.js?

Comment: @VBart Because there are less than 5 static files to serve, and the tiny app requires Node, so I think using Node alone may be better in deplyment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line, `fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8')` the encoding is set to `'utf8'`.  It needs to be `'binary'`.

Also, the `res.end(file_content)` function needs to pass the right encoding.  Try `res.end(file_content, 'binary')`.

I had the same issue and had to figure it out myself, this answer doesn't seem to exist anywhere online.