# How to add font-awesome to Angular 2 + CLI project

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, font-awesome

I'm using Angular 2+ and Angular CLI.

How do I add font-awesome to my project?

Comment: I have the same issue. It's like the files are ignored by the CLI and not copied when in dev mode. That said, the file are there in the /dist dir, when a build is done.

Comment: I do not understand, why do we need to add font-awesome via npm, couldn't we just link to font-awesome cdn? What am I missing?

Comment: @RosdiKasim you can link to the cdn form your index file. There are cases when you wouldn't want to though. Corporate projects may not allow external sources; CDN could go down; CLI update may need to update the index.html file so you'll have to make sure it doesn't overwrite your current links; font-awesome could be a dependency for another npm lib; you want to lock font-awesome to a certain version; your build process could depend on it...(and so on, you get the idea) In the end, up to how you want to bring it in.

Comment: Ok thanks... looks like I am not missing much... I just want to make sure I understand the pros and cons... cheers.

Comment: See also the official documentation for adding JS or CSS : https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries#adding-a-library-to-the-runtime-global-scope

Answer (score 537, accepted):

After Angular 2.0 final release, **the structure of the Angular2 CLI project has been changed** — you don't need any vendor files, no system.js — only webpack. So you do:

1. `npm install font-awesome --save`
2. In the `angular-cli.json` file locate the `styles[]` array and  add  font-awesome references directory here, like below:

   ```
   "apps": [
       {
         "root": "src",
         "outDir": "dist",
         ....
         "styles": [
             "styles.css",
             "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
             "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" // -here webpack will automatically build a link css element out of this!?
         ],
         ...
     }
     ]
   ],
   ```

   > In more recent versions of Angular, use the `angular.json` file instead, without the `../`. For example, use `"node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"`.
3. Place some font-awesome icons in any html file you want:

   ```html
   <i class="fa fa-american-sign-language-interpreting fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"> </i>
   ```
4. Stop the application <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> then re-run the  app using `ng serve` because the watchers are only for the src folder and angular-cli.json is not observed for changes.
5. Enjoy your awesome icons!

Comment: Great, thanks! You might want to update your HTML code snippet in point 3. Missing some <

Comment: yes Lindsay Ward, you are right. Problem is, for some reason stack overflow editor is hiding the <> tags when an  i element is involved- even if they are in the special code block section. I delete that knowingly. I don't know how to do it corectly. None of the skipping character method that i know of works. Sorry about that :)

Comment: This is the correct way, thanks for sharing. Do you know where's this documented?

Comment: Can you explain what `addons` does? I see [it's documented as](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular-cli/lib/config/schema.json) *"Configuration reserved for installed third party addons."*, but I cannot find any handling [in the Angular-CLI code](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/search?type=Code&q=addons).

Comment: Unfortunately @Arjan & @bjorkblom - i couldn't find any docs regarding this `addons` filed...
This has been in my attention for a while now.. I will update my answer once i find something.

Comment: Minor issue, bootstrap.css is included twice in styles

Comment: I do not understand, why do we need to add font-awesome via npm, couldn't we just link to font-awesome cdn? What am I missing?

Comment: @Rosdi Kasim Jan - you could do that - but in bigger apps generally you don't use cdns.

First because somebody can hack them and compromise your app indirectly.

Second because it's not just font-awesome - you need other external libraries like bootstrap, dnd libraries etc - if you have separate http request - to a cdn - for each of them, it's bad performance.
What you do instead, is download with npm - and bundle with all your code in one single file using webpack or something, minify and uglify that  -- and that's how you can run your app on mobile -- where the resources are low.

Comment: Note: the `addons` property is no longer used. It's sufficient to include the `font-awesome.css` file under `styles`. See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/include-font-awesome.md

Comment: @AIon now "addons" property is removed from angular-cli. Now when I build the app, it is unable to load the .woff2, woff and ttf files.

Comment: @indra257 i've updated the answer, by removing the `addons`. - @0X2D9A3 says it's ***sufficient to include the font-awesome.css in the styles array*** and lot's of people pointing to that being right. Please make sure you got everything as described. I didn't test it personally -  I mostly use elm this days,  a much better experience.

Comment: It runs fine when I do ng serve. When I do ng build it runs fine too but the console shows it is unable to load tff, woff and woff2 files. I tested this with an empty app and just included font-awesome

Comment: @indra257 i've digged down into the Angular source code - `WebpackResourceLoader` - here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40ngtools/webpack/src/resource_loader.ts#L114, and i think what the problem is: cli uses `UTF-8` encoding to read the files.. and from what i understand here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372997/why-node-js-failed-to-serve-woff-files - the `woff2`, `woff`, and `tff` need to be read as `binary`, not `utf-8`. Not sure what to do about it. Angular folks need to fix this - there is no setting for now, except changing the source code.

Comment: @AIon Can you suggest any workaround. I think I can't deploy my application with errors in the console.

Comment: @indra257 i would clone the repo and modify the Angular source code, like this:  take out the extension form the `filePath` argument which is passed into the `get` function as string, check if the extension is `woff2` or `woff` or `tff`. If True `return this._compile(filePath, readFileSync(filePath, 'binary'))` - else leve it as it is: `return this._compile(filePath, readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8'))`. Not complicated. Leave the `.then` branch inside both intact. But i say all this of the top of my head. Didn't test it. Usually It's bad to do this because you loose it on the next Angular update.

Comment: @Alon Side question - are you using Bootstrap with Material ? I noticed `../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`

Comment: In angular 4, this is not working if i try to build it with ng build -prod, and than when in prod version of the code, font-awesome still show as square.

Comment: @ user2412555 i'm trying to understand your situation. Does it work on dev but not on production? are there any errors/warnings in the console? Thanks.

Comment: Could you get me some help with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48528476/webpack-loading-iconic-fonts)

Comment: Update: With Angular 6.0.0 the filename is changed from .angular-cli.json to angular.json

Comment: I had to change the css path to `node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css`. See that i am pointing to the min file (more efficient).

Comment: Be careful that you are using the right version of font-awesome from npm, as the font you are trying to copy over. I think this wasn't working, but then realized I was using a different version of font-awesome.

Comment: This answer is outdated, this installs FA version 4.7, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52456022/3596441)

Comment: Angular 9+ supports **`ng add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome`**. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46596735/11457981) answer.

Answer (score 141):

If you are using SASS, you can just install it via npm

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

and import it in your `/src/styles.scss` with:

```
$fa-font-path: "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts";
@import "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

Tip: Whenever possible, avoid to mess with `angular-cli` infrastructure. ;)

Comment: It's the best solution imo. Works like a charm after a `ng build && ng serve -w`. It's easier and safer to let scss build style + fonts than trying to change angular-cli infra ;)

Comment: Best answer. Minor improvement: use `~` instead of `../node_modules/`, e.g. `@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';`

Comment: not working for me with angular4  and scss. I can see the css but not the icon

Comment: I have same problem on Angular4

Comment: Use the `.css` import from `~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css` and it works fine (default fa-font-path) for angular4/cli

Comment: @F.D.Castel +1 for the avoid messing with the `angular-cli` infrastructure :-)

Answer (score 77):

The top answer is a bit outdated and there is a slightly easier way.

1. install through npm

   `npm install font-awesome --save`
2. in your `style.css`:

   `@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';`

   or in your `style.scss`:

   `$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
    @import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';`

   **Edit:** as noted in the comments the line for fonts must be changed on newer versions to `$fa-font-path: "../../../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts";`

using the `~` will make sass look into `node_module`. It's better to do it this way than with the relative path. The reason is that if you upload a component on npm, and you import font-awesome inside the component scss then it will work properly with ~ and not with the relative path that will be wrong at that point.

This method works for any npm module that contains css. It works for scss as well. **However** if you are importing css into your styles.scss it won't work (and maybe vice versa). [Here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file)

Comment: Still getting the same error after following your steps.

Comment: Failed to load .ttf, woff and woff2 files

Comment: I am using cli 1.0 . Just to double check, I created one sample app and just loaded font-awesome and deployed the app. still getting that error.

Comment: @indra257 I had to add
$fa-font-path: "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts"; in styles.scss for above instructions to work

Comment: I dont have style.scss file in my project. Do I have to follow any other steps to after adding styles.scss file.

Comment: I was trying this, but was getting warnings during the build process: `unable to find path user/dev/~font-awesome....`. The problem was using the `~` with the `$fa-font-path`, if I used a relative path instead of the `~` here it worked fine. Maybe the tilde is not suppose to be used for paths other than imports?

Comment: @Brian I'm not sure, it worked for me so far, maybe a new version made it not work

Answer (score 60):

There are 3 parts to using Font-Awesome in Angular Projects

1. Installation
2. Styling (CSS/SCSS)
3. Usage in Angular

**Installation**

Install from NPM and save to your package.json

```
npm install --save font-awesome
```

**Styling**
***If using CSS***

Insert into your style.css

```css
@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
```

**Styling**
***If using SCSS***

Insert into your style.scss

```css
$fa-font-path: "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts";
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
```

**Usage with plain Angular 2.4+ 4+**

```html
<i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i>
```

**Usage with [Angular Material](https://github.com/angular/components)**

In your app.module.ts modify the constructor to use the `MdIconRegistry`

```js
export class AppModule {
  constructor(matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry) {
    matIconRegistry.registerFontClassAlias('fontawesome', 'fa');
  }
}
```

and add `MatIconModule` to your `@NgModule` imports

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatIconModule,
      ....
  ],
  declarations: ....
}
```

---

Now in any template file you can now do

```html
<mat-icon fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-area-chart"></mat-icon>
```

Comment: Do you have any problem with bundling the font-awesome. I think the main issue is bundling when we use Cli. tff, woff, woff2 files are not getting bundled.

Comment: I just created a sample application and followed your steps. Bundled the app using ng build. In the console I am still seeing  Unable to load woff and woff2 files error

Comment: That's correct. It works perfectly fine with ng serve. With ng build, it works fine, but console shows it is unable to load some woff, woff2 files.

Comment: I don't see the same problem, so I expect something is wrong with your build/config files. I suggest you replicate your problem with a test case and create a new question with it.

Comment: I created an empty app by using angular-cli and added font-awesome. Which files do you want me to check..

Answer (score 51):

**UPDATE Feb 2020:**
[fortawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome) package now supports [`ng add`](https://angular.io/cli/add) but it is available [only for angular 9](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/README.md#compatiblity-table) and up:

```
ng add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
```

**UPDATE 8 Oct 2019:**

You can use a new package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome

```
npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

Add `FontAwesomeModule` to imports in `src/app/app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Tie the icon to the property in your component `src/app/app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  faCoffee = faCoffee;
}
```

Use the icon in the template `src/app/app.component.html`:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

### Option 1:

You can use [angular-font-awesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome) npm module

```
npm install --save font-awesome angular-font-awesome
```

**Import the module:**

```
...
//
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';
@NgModule({
  //...
  imports: [
    //...
    AngularFontAwesomeModule
  ],
  //...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If you're using Angular CLI, add the font-awesome CSS to styles inside the angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
],
```

*NOTE: If using SCSS preprocessor just change the css for scss*

**Example Use:**

```
<fa name="cog" animation="spin"></fa>
```

### Option 2:

There is an [official story](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/include-font-awesome.md) for that now

Install the font-awesome library and add the dependency to `package.json`

`npm install --save font-awesome`

**Using CSS**

To add Font Awesome CSS icons to your app...

```
// in .angular-cli.json

"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
]
```

**Using SASS**

Create an empty file `_variables.scss` in `src/`.

Add the following to `_variables.scss`:

`$fa-font-path : '../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts';`
In `styles.scss` add the following:

```
@import 'variables';
@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

**Test**

Run ng serve to run your application in develop mode, and navigate to http://localhost:4200.

To verify Font Awesome has been set up correctly, change `src/app/app.component.html` to the following...

```
<h1>
  {{title}} <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
</h1>
```

After saving this file, return to the browser to see the Font Awesome icon next to the app title.

Also there is a related question [Angular CLI outputs the font-awesome font files the dist root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584865/angular-cli-outputs-the-font-awesome-font-files-the-dist-root) as by default angular cli outputs the fonts in to the `dist` root, which is by the way not an issue at all.

Comment: When using option 1, remove `../` from in front of `"../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"`

Comment: WHY am I supposed to use the new angular package?  It seems way more of a PITA to import them individually.

Comment: @MDave you do not have to, there is plenty of options how to use bootstrap in angular apps.

Comment: just a quick note that with the most recent option you still need to `npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome`, might be worth adding this to the answer

Comment: @User632716 it is there, on the first line

Comment: I mean that `npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons` in your answer is not equal to `npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome` in the docs, apologies if im missing something obvious.

Comment: @User632716 OK just added the missing package to npm install command.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I was searching for Angular 9 + font awesome. UPDATE Feb 2020 is the most helpful thing after wasting 1 day.

Comment: Thanks for angular 9+ font awesome update, it worked for me

Comment: The update is also awesome. Thank you.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something. Older package used to include font-awesome.css in styles and allowed to use any icon on a page right away with WebFont+CSS flavor. Now they are only allowing JS flavor with a package? How to include entire css for 90% of simple cases where I don't want to touch *.ts to import individual icons? In the doc they still mentioning that I should find and import css from the package, but this css no longer have character mapping and font loading...

Answer (score 21):

Accepted answer is outdated.

For angular 9 and Fontawesome 5

1. Install FontAwesome

   npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free --save
2. Register it on angular.json under styles

   "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"
3. Use it on your application

Comment: Thanks! We need this answer up up up up up

Comment: Thank you, your answer is still the easiest one :)

Answer (score 17):

Thought I would throw in my resolution to this since font-awesome is now installed differently according to their documentation.

```
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Why it is fortawesome now escapes me but thought I would stick with the most recent version rather than falling back to the old font-awesome.

Then I imported it into my scss

```
$fa-font-path: "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/v4-shims";
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 16):

With `Angular2` RC5 and `angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8` you can achieve this with css imports.

Just install font awesome:

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

and then import font-awesome in one of your configured style files:

```
@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
```

(style files are configured in `angular-cli.json`)

Comment: Looks like it is trying to import but getting an error `zone.js:101 - GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css 404 (Not Found) `... file actually exists but looks like `localhost:4200` is not running from the root of this folder ... How to package up font-awesome to `localhost:4200` root folder ...

Comment: also I am using `angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2` and style file configuration in `angular-cli.json` is not working ...

Comment: hmm that is strange, maybe upgrade to `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8` ?

Answer (score 7):

Many instructions above work, I suggest looking at those. However, something to note:

Using `<i class="fas fa-coffee"></i>` *did not work* in my project (new practice project only a week old) after installation and the sample icon here was also copied to the clipboard from Font Awesome within the past week.

This`<i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>` **does work**. If after installing Font Awesome on your project it isn't yet working, I suggest checking the class on your icon to remove the 's' to see if it works then.

Answer (score 7):

For fontawesome 5.x+ the most simplest way would be the following,

install using npm package:
`npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

In your `styles.scss` file include:

```
$fa-font-path: "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts";
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
```

Note: if you have `_variables.scss` file then it's more appropriate to include the `$fa-font-path` inside it and not in `styles.scss` file.

Comment: I ended up using your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For Angular 6,

First `npm install font-awesome --save`

Add  `node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css` to ***angular.json***.

Remember **not** to add any dots in front of the `node_modules/`.

Comment: I end up with just squares for the images when I do this.

Comment: same here, how did you remove the squares? @Gargoyle

Answer (score 5):

This post describes how to integrate **Fontawesome 5** into **Angular 6** (Angular 5 and previous versions will also work, but then you have to adjust my writings)

**Option 1: Add the css-Files**

Pro: Every icon will be included

Contra: Every icon will be included (bigger app size because all fonts are included)

Add the following package:

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts
```

Afterwards add the following lines to your angular.json:

```
"app": {
....
"styles": [
....
"node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts/css/fontawesome.css",
"node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts/css/fa-regular.css",
"node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts/css/fa-brands.css",
"node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts/css/fa-solid.css"
],
...    
}
```

**Option 2: Angular package**

Pro: Smaller app size

Contra: You have to include every icon you want to use seperatly

Use the FontAwesome 5 Angular package:

```
npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
```

Just follow their documentation to add the icons. They use the svg-icons, so you only have to add the svgs / icons, you really use.

Comment: Notice your paths start with @fortawesome.  Notice the word 'FORT', not 'FONT'  My install is doing this too.  Anyone know what is up with this?

Comment: Never mind, apparently they have some renaming structuring going on.  See [This Github Post](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/2861)

Comment: @Aniketkale what is not working? I presented two options

Answer (score 4):

There are many good answers here. But if you tried all of them and still getting squares instead fontawesome icons, check your css rules. In my case I had the following rule:

```
* {
  font-family: Roboto-Light, Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif !important;
}
```

And it overrides fontawesome fonts. Just replacing `*` selector to `body` solved my problem:

```
body {
  font-family: Roboto-Light, Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that did it for me granted now I have to figure out how to get the fonts working since doing it in a body selector doesn't work for me

Comment: @jgerstle, specifying font in `body` should work, be sure, that you don't override the font somewhere else, may be you overriding it in `h*` or `p` tags as we are usually do.

Comment: Ya something seems to be overriding it but I don't think it's my own code I think it might just be the chrome defaults it's weird though because I set it to !important and it still seems to get overridden. I'll have to look more into it.

Comment: I got it using :not(.fa) to keep the same * selector, but not target anything using font-awesome

Answer (score 3):

After some experimentation I managed to get the following working:

1. Install with npm:

   ```
   npm install font-awesome --save
   ```
2. add to **angular-cli-build.js** file:

   ```
   vendorNpmFiles : [
       font-awesome/**/*.+(css|css.map|otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)',
   ]
   ```
3. add to **index.html**

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   ```

---

The key was to include the font file types in the angular-cli-build.js file

**.+(css|css.map|otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)**

Comment: just a heads up there is no `angular-cli-build.js` in the latest webpack branch

Comment: Also, [vendorNpmFiles is not found in the current Angular-CLI code](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/search?type=Code&q=vendorNpmFiles). Seeing Alon's accepted answer, I guess this is outdated?

Comment: @Arjan yep, this answer is outdated...this was for the pre webpack CLI. Alon's answer is the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I'm using angular ^4.0.0 and Electron ^1.4.3

If you have issues with **ElectronJS** or similar and have a sort of 404 error, a possible workaround is to uedit your `webpack.config.js`, by adding (and by assuming that you have the font-awesome node module installed through npm or in the package.json file):

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
     { from: 'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts', to: 'assets' },
     { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' }
]),
```

Note that the webpack configuration I'm using has `src/app/dist` as output, and, in dist, an `assets` folder is created by webpack:

```
// our angular app
entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/app/app',
},

// Config for our build files
output: {
    path: helpers.root('src/app/dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
},
```

So basically, what is currently happening is:

- Webpack is copying the fonts folder to the dev assets folder.
- Webpack is copying the dev assets folder to the `dist` assets folder

Now, when the build process will be finished, the application will need to look for the `.scss` file and the folder containing the icons, resolving them properly.
To resolve them, I've used this in my webpack config:

```
// support for fonts
{
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
    loader: 'file-loader?name=dist/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
},
```

Finally, in the `.scss` file, I'm importing the font-awesome .scss and defining the path of the fonts, which is, again, `dist/assets/font-awesome/fonts`. The path is `dist` because in my webpack.config the output.path is set as `helpers.root('src/app/dist');`

So, in `app.scss`:

```
$fa-font-path: "dist/assets/font-awesome/fonts";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

Note that, in this way, it will define the font path (used later in the .scss file) and import the .scss file using `~font-awesome` to resolve the font-awesome path in `node_modules`.

This is quite tricky, but it's the only way I've found to get around the 404 error issue with Electron.js

Answer (score 2):

Starting from https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter, after having tested a lot of different configuration combination, here is what I did to get it working with AoT.

As already said many times, in my `app.component.scss`:

```
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts" !default;
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

Then in webpack.config.js (actually webpack.commong.js in the starter pack) :

In the plugins section:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' },
    { from: 'src/meta'},
    { from: 'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts', to: 'assets/fonts/' }
]),
```

In the rules section:

```
,
{
    test: /\.(eot|woff2?|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/,
    use: 'file-loader?name=/assets/fonts/[name].[ext]'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wasted several hours trying to get the latest version of FontAwesome 5.2.0 working with AngularCLI 6.0.3 and Material Design.  I followed the npm installation instructions off of the FontAwesome website

Their latest docs instruct you do install using the following:

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

After wasting several hours I finally uninstalled it and installed font awesome using the following command (this installs FontAwesome v4.7.0):

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

Now it's working fine using:

```
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts" !default;
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
<mat-icon fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-android"></mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Angular Font Awesome package

> npm install --save font-awesome angular-font-awesome

and then import in your module:

```
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';
     @NgModule({
       //...
      imports: [
        //...
        AngularFontAwesomeModule
      ],
      //...
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

and import the style in angular-cli file:

```
   "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
    ],
```

see more details about the package in npm library:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome

and then use it like this:

`<i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>`

Answer (score 2):

[Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers) gives you `scalable`vector icons that can instantly be customized—size, color, drop shadow, and anything that can be done with the power of `CSS`.

Create a new project and navigate into the project.

```
ng new navaApp
cd navaApp
```

Install the font-awesome library and add the dependency to `package.json`.

```
npm install --save font-awesome
```

**Using CSS**

To add Font Awesome CSS icons to your app...

```
// in angular.json
"build": {
"options": {
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
 }
}
```

**Using SASS**

Create new project with SASS:

```
ng new cli-app --style=scss
```

To use with existing project with `CSS`:

Rename `src/styles.css` to `src/styles.scss`
Change `angular.json` to look for `styles.scss` instead of `css`:

```
// in angular.json
"build": {
"options": {
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss"
],
}
}
```

Make sure to change `styles.css` to `styles.scss`.

Create an empty file `_variables.scss` in `src/`.

Add the following to `_variables.scss`:

```
$fa-font-path : '../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts';
```

In `styles.scss` add the following:

```
@import 'variables';
@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

Comment: Its A Good Question.
It's always been a question for me

Answer (score 2):

To use Font Awesome 5 in your Angular project, insert the code below in the  of the src/index.html file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Using LESS (not SCSS) and Angular 2.4.0 and standard Webpack (not Angular CLI, the following worked for me:

```
npm install --save font-awesome
```

and (in my app.component.less):

```
@import "~font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less";
```

and of course you may need this obvious and highly intuitive snippet (in module.loaders in webpack.conf)

```
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?(v=)?(\d+)(\.\d+)*)?$/,
            loader: 'file?name=graphics/[name].[ext]'
        },
```

The loader is there to fix webpack errors of the kind

```
"Module parse failed: \node_modules\font-awesome\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0 Unexpected token (1:0)"
```

and the regexp matches those svg-references (with or without version specification). Depending on your webpack setup you might not need it or you may need something else.

Answer (score 1):

For webpack2 use:

```
{
 test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?(v=)?(\d+)(\.\d+)*)?$/,
                    loader: "file-loader"
}
```

instead of `file-loader?name=/assets/fonts/[name].[ext]`

Answer (score 1):

Add it in your package.json as 
"devDependencies" 
font-awesome : "version number"

Go to Command Prompt type npm command which you configured.

Comment: You'll want to add font-awesome to your 'dependencies', not 'dev-dependencies' as you'll need it in your final build. Also the instructions above do not answer how the Angular project will pick it up once they are added to you package.json file.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to use Font Awesome 5+ and most answers focus on older versions

For the new Font Awesome 5+ the angular project hasn't been released yet, so if you want to make use of the examples mentioned on the font awesome website atm you need to use a work around. (especially the fas, far classes instead of the fa class)

I've just imported the cdn to Font Awesome 5 in my styles.css. Just added this in case it helps someone find the answer quicker than I did :-)

Code in Style.css

```
@import "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css";
```

Comment: I tried this. Works good in local, but when I try to build it, icons went missing.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you cant install package throw npm. You can always edit index.html and add font awesome CSS in the head. And then just used it in the project.

Answer (score 1):

For Angular 9 using `ng` :

```
ng add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.6.x
```

[Look Here For More Information](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 1):

Now there is few ways to install fontAwesome on Angular CLI:

```
ng add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome

OR using yarn

yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
yarn add @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
yarn add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome

OR Using NPM

npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
```

Reference here: https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 11

```
npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome --save
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core --save
npm install @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons --save
```

And then in `app.module.ts` at imports array

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
```

And then in `any.component.ts`

```
turningGearIcon = faCogs;
```

And then `any.component.html`

```
<fa-icon [icon]="turningGearIcon"></fa-icon>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use free version of font awesome - bootstrap, use this :

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

If you are building angular project, you also need to add these imports in your angular.json :

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js"
        ]
```