# How to add font-awesome using angular-cli@beta11

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have moved to the newest version of angular cli that uses webpack.
I have trouble finding out how to actually force the compiler to add custom  font files to the dist folder so I can use them in my application.
I tried with additionalEntries in angular-cli.json but it doesn't work.

```
{
"project": {
"version": "1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2",
"name": "print-dashboard"
},
"apps": [
{
  "main": "src/main.ts",
  "tsconfig": "src/tsconfig.json",
  "mobile": false,
  "additionalEntries": [
    "assets/font-awesome/fonts/**"
  ]
}
],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
  "protractor": {
  "config": "config/protractor.conf.js"
  }
},
  "test": {
  "karma": {
  "config": "config/karma.conf.js"
  }
 },
  "defaults": {
  "prefix": "app",
  "sourceDir": "src",
  "styleExt": "scss",
  "prefixInterfaces": false,
  "lazyRoutePrefix": "+"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put any "extra" files (like folders for images, fonts etc) in the /public folder and they will be incorporated into your build automatically

Answer (score 0):

with `angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8` you can use css imports (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39238788/1787388)