# angular cli - adding cdn scripts/styles as global priority

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I've added to fresh build of angular-cli, some styles and script in head of index.html, but it seems that webpack is not loading those files. It might be problem since those files are loaded from cdn.
Is there any way to add globaly scripts/styles from cdn as

```
 apps[0].scripts // styles section in angular-cli.json 
 apps[0].styles //script section in angular-cli.json
```

Comment: Looking for an answer for this. But, after searching found that this is the recommended way to do that. Explains an example for font-awesome - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796541/how-to-add-font-awesome-to-angular-2-cli-project/39557671

Answer (score 2):

you have to add your scripts and styles directly in angular-cli.json