# addons removed in angular-cli.json whats the replacement

Tags: angular-cli, webfonts

angular-cli RC 1 has removed addons in the .angular-cli.json file.
Before I was doing this:

```
    "addons": [
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/fontawesome-webfont.woff"
  ],
```

So now when the addons tag has been removed how do I import the webfonts?

Comment: Hi Martin, I wonder if you have any information on this matter.

Comment: this is the new way to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/42334407/1147577