# How to add font-awesome to angular 4+ project

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I am having issues adding font-awesome to my Angular 4+ project using scss. I have tried the many steps given here: [How to add font-awesome to Angular 2 + CLI project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796541/how-to-add-font-awesome-to-angular-2-cli-project) for scss based projects mainly adding `@import '~/../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';` to `styles.scss` and `$fa-font-path : '~/../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts';` to `variables.scss`. The thing is it compiles and it seems like it is working because I at least get a block where the icon is supposed to be, whereas without it I get nothing, but that's it. I can try importing the css files in the angular-cli, but I'd rather do it the scss way. Has anyone had success with this in an angular 4+ project?

I'm posting  in a new topic because it seems like it's an issue in Angular 4, not angular 2, based on the comments in that post, and that post is old.

Comment: If you don't want it to compile with webpack bundler through your angular-cli.json you need to include it as an asset and target the link to the asset.

Comment: I want to import it in my scss

Comment: I got it in the end using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45147045/1259742

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by pointing to your font files in your styles

```
// styles.scss
$fa-font-path: "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts";
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
```

Or as others have mentioned, you can load through webpack

```
// angular-cli.json
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
    "styles.scss"
]
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a much **simpler** way of doing this (without need of copying folders,
adding something in angular-cli json and using "node_modules" while importing).

Here are the steps:

1. Install FontAwesome package as usual:

   ```
   npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
   ```
2. Add following lines to your `styles.scss` file:

   ```
   $fa-font-path: "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts";
   @import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
   @import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
   @import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
   @import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands"; // OPTIONAL. Remove if you are not using this
   ```

Please also **note** that since FontAwesome 5 `fa` is [considered](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4) as `fas`
which means in case of using `fa` in html you'll see solid (bolder) icons.
So make sure you are using `far` instead of `fa` for regular (non-bold)
fonts if you are going to upgrade from earlier versions of FontAwesome.
(This might require from you to upgrade to Pro version.)

Answer (score 2):

Npm install font awesome and Just add to styles in .angular-cli.json file and it will bundle for you.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue when I do that (box instead of icon). Plus I'd rather put it in my scss files and not in the angular-cli.

Comment: Are you including font-awesome.css? You can also import in your scss file as you are saying using import.

Comment: I want to import it in my scss file using import but I'm getting boxes instead of icons. No I used the scss file like I said I want to use scss. If all else fails I guess I can use css, but I'd rather be consistent.

Comment: Can you share the so i can take a look?

Comment: what/how exactly should I share?

Comment: thanks for the help as i commented above I got it working by using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45147045/1259742

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you install 5.2.x version of font-awesome

1. `npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`
2. copy `webfonts` folder inside of `node_module/fortawesome/fontawesome-free`  to `assets/scss/` folder ( or any folder inside assets )
3. add `$fa-font-path: "webfonts"; to the`styless.scss
4. finally add following imports to the `styles.scss`

   @import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";

   @import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";

   @import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";

There is another better way of doing it [documented](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular) but that explain how you want to add it as an angular module in my case I would like fonts to do its job in the simplest way possible.