# Font-awesome icons not loading on Angular4 project

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I'm working on an angular 4 project using font-awesome, i followed this guide to install the library with npm:
[How to add font-awesome to Angular 2 + CLI project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796541/how-to-add-font-awesome-to-angular-2-cli-project)

i've configured the project to compile the scss stylesheets with the ng-serve command, my styles paths of the angular-cli.json looks like this:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/main.scss",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss"

      ],
```

i want to make a button with an address card icon on it, i'm also working with Bootstrap 4, so it looks like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><span class="fas fa-address-card"></span></button>
```

but when it loads, it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You should be using the class `fa` instead of `fas`. This class sets the font-face.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should be using the class fa instead of fas. The fa class sets the font-face. (hat tip to @mike-hill)

View source on 
http://fontawesome.io/icon/address-card/

Comment: OMG it took me way too long to find this answer - why the hell do they generate the examples like this on the homepage? <i class="fas fa-home"></i>

Comment: @bigbasti It is for Font Awesome 5. You are probably using an older version.

Answer (score 4):

## Font-awesome version 5+

**fa prefix** has been depricated from version 5. In order to use **fas prefix** install version 5+ and include in your styles.

**install:**

yourapp$npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free --save

**package.json**

```
"styles": [
   "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css",
   "src/styles.scss"
  ],
```

Comment: I think it should be added to the `angular.json` file not `package.json`

Answer (score 2):

I had everything correct and it was working. I made changes to the design and the icons were displayed as box.

The issue was font-family. I had mentioned the font-family in css to all elements: `*{ font-family: "inter" }` .

Changing it to `html, body{ font-family: "inter" }` fixed it and font awesome started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

After adding dependencies to Angular.json or Angular-cli.json.
1) stop running App
2) start it
It will recognize new resources

Comment: It took me almost 2 days to figure out my issue.. Thank you for mentioning to restart app after adding new resources..

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have properly setup the project requirements to use font-awesome icons by including them in styles[] in angular.jason or simply importing them by like this:

```
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
```

in the component css file. Then it is necessary to have "fa" class in addition to what the font-icons markup gives you. Alternatively you can do like this:

```
<div class="fa">
<i class="whateverTheIconClassYouWant"></i>
</div>
```

Inside the div with class="fa" you can directly copy paste the code that is provided in font awsome website.

Hope this helps!
Happy coding!!!!

Answer (score 0):

after installing font awesome, you can add this to index.html

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```