# Font-awesome icons not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, angular, font-awesome

Font awesome icons recently stopped displaying. They just appear as small boxes like this everywhere:

[image]

Here is the icon in this particular component:

```
<i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg"></i>
```

I have just tried updating Font awesome to version 5 using one their 'kits' on their website here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4

This just tells you to insert this into your head tag:

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c61d55aa48.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Which I've done (as I'm using Angular, I've placed this in the index.html file) but the icons are still displaying as above. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: it's like this i think <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg" />

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is this not exactly the same way I already have it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Let's look at docs how icons can be shown](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/usage/features.md#basic-use). So we can type like that:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['far', 'square']"></fa-icon>
<br>
<fa-icon [icon]="['far', 'check-square']"></fa-icon>
```

[The complete stackblitz example can be seen here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-font-awesome-starter?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**UPDATE:**

It is [necessary to install](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome):

```
  npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
$ npm install @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
# See Compatibility table below to choose a correct version
$ npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@<version>
```

Your `app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faSquare, faCheckSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faSquare as farSquare, faCheckSquare as farCheckSquare } from 
  '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
import { faStackOverflow, faGithub, faMedium } from 
  '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, FontAwesomeModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    library.add(faSquare, faCheckSquare, farSquare, farCheckSquare, 
      faStackOverflow, faGithub, faMedium);
  }
}
```

then `app.component.html`

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h2>Using Solid Icons</h2>
  <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'square']"></fa-icon>
  <br>
  <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'check-square']"></fa-icon>
</div>
```

Comment: @BailP I am glad that it helped to you:)

Answer (score 2):

[FontAwesome 4.7.0](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/) **does not** contain the `fa-trash-alt` icon.

[FontAwesome 5](https://fontawesome.com/icons/trash-alt?style=solid) **does** contain the `fa-trash-alt` icon.

So if you'd include **FontAwesome Version 5+** `fa-trash-alt` should work as expected:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added the link you provided above to the head tag in my index.html file and the same issue still persists (icons being displayed as above in the image)

Comment: Since you're using Angul, try using the `fa` instead of `fas`. Something like: `<i class="fa fa-trash-alt fa-lg"></i>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705834/font-awesome-icons-not-loading-on-angular4-project

Comment: I've tried this as well and it still as the same result