# Webpack: loading iconic fonts

Tags: webpack, font-awesome

I've installed `font-awesome`:

```
npm install font-awesome
```

I've added these rules on webconfig:

```
{ test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
{ test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
```

Into my `main.scss` I've added this import:

```
@import "font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

`font-awesome` css rules are loaded into browser but, fonts are not loaded.

It seems fonts are requested by browser on `_localhost/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0`. However, the response is the main html page:

[image]

I think the problem is related with fonts are into `nodo_modules/font-awesome/fonts/`. I think these files are not able to be reached because they are not "moved" into a reachable place by webpack... So, where are they located after webpack ends "bundle process"?

**EDIT**

I've changed my test by:

```
{ test: /\.(ttf|eot|otf|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
```

However when browser tries to load font, the response keep being an html:

[image]
[image]

**EDIT 2**

I've just realized that into my `tsconfig.json` file contains this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2015", "es2016", "es2017"],
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    "compiled",
    "src/main.browser.aot.ts",
    "e2e/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "useWebpackText": true,
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useCache": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

Does it has something to do?

Comment: I have the same issue, but I ended up separating the fonts and include them in the HTML file. :(

Comment: I think the problem is related with fonts are into `nodo_modules/font-awesome/fonts/`. I think these files are not able to be reached because they are not "moved" into a reachable place by webpack...

Comment: Sounds promising!  Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I've added an issue on `url-loader` repository [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader/issues/107#issuecomment-361877947)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is accurate, because i can't install [your repo](https://github.com/jeusdi/fontawesome) - i'm getting some weird, incorrect dependency errors. But i think the issue is:

**Your regex does not capture the `FontAwesome.otf` file.**

[image: font awesome fonts not loading properly - because of bad regex]

This test should work now..

```
{ test: /\.(ttf|eot|otf|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
```

Comment: I've just edited my code. Sadly, it seems to be failing yet... I've edited post. It's really, really strange!

Comment: @Jordi let's figure out if this **is webpack/bundling fault or something else**. Please create a small starter project - in which you **use font awesome alone**. Just to see how it behaves. Then, if it works correctly - compare what files are loaded - against what you have in the above pictures. If the same files are loaded, then it means webpack does something to the contents when moving the files. The idea is to isolate the problem more and more - and making sure other variables that seem unrelated don't play a role. Is not fun to do - but i think is a good enough approach at this point.