# Fontawesome icons not showing in angular project

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I have installed fontawesome with npm using `npm install --save font-awesome`

Then I added the css to my angular.json like this:

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

Then I added this to my html file:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
  </button>
```

On my webpage it's showing an empty button, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your Angular version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add font-awesome to Angular 2 + CLI project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796541/how-to-add-font-awesome-to-angular-2-cli-project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    You can give the address in the styles.scss instead of the address in the package
    this way should work
```

### @import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";

Comment: Where do I put this import?

Comment: styles.scss in root project

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upgrade to the Angular form of FontAwesome

This can be resolved by:

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install --save @fortawesome/free--svg-icons
npm install --save @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
```

check to make sure you have the right version of [angular-fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome) for your angular version.

add/edit the following files:

angular.module.ts

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
```

angular.component.ts

```
import {FaIconLibrary, FontAwesomeModule} from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import {far} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
import {fas} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

constructor(
   library: FaIconLibrary,
) {
  library.addIconPacks(fas, far);
}
```

edit all icon tags to

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'icon-name']" >
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because of the font file is missing. So you need a way to include your font file in your css.

In your `styles.scss` file add:
just check the relative path from your `node_modules` folder.

```
$fa-font-path : "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts";
@import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
```

Comment: Be careful. The command "npm i font-awesome" install the version 4.7 of font-awesome, whereas the relative path of your import is looking for the folder of the new font-awesome 5. So I bet it will not work. The correct path is: 
--> node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
OR --> node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css

Comment: Ohh.. Okay... That's why I said to check the relative path of the directories... So this method doesn't work with font-awesome4?

Answer (score 0):

The proper step is:

1. within the project folder: **npm install font-awesome**
   (no need to --save if npm greater than 5)
2. go to **angular.json**, add this line in "styles":
   **"./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"**
3. Restart the server (**control-C** and **ng serve** again) to see the effect.
4. if not work, make sure you see the right code for the icon code in official font-awesome website.

note:
some version of angular, need to be: **../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css**