# 'Font awesome' icons are not showing even though package is installed on angular

Tags: css, angular

I need to add some social media icons I'm not sure other than font awesome if there is anything else I can use for free, I installed the package and added

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
```

here is my Style.css :

```
@font-face {
font-family: "FutoSans";
src: local("FutoSans"), url(assets/fonts/FutoSans-Bold.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

here is my angular.json

```
 "styles": [
          {
            "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css"
  
          },
          "src/styles.css",
       "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"
         
        ],
```

but when I use for example the following tag, it does not show anything

```
<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fontawesome icons not showing in angular project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65009383/fontawesome-icons-not-showing-in-angular-project)

Comment: Have you put the FontAwesome CSS into your CSS file?

Comment: @DhanaD which file i should add?app.component.css?

Answer (score 0):

please read the documentation given by the fontawesome angular package. You can get the icons with:

TS

```
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'; <---

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  faCoffee = faCoffee; <----
}
```

HTML

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>
```

If you want to use only the CSS classes in your HTML download the free fontawesome version (npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free) and include the CSS and .js in your angular.json like this:

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.min.js"
        ]
```

then you can use the "fab fa-icon" classes

Comment: Install npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free (not the angular fontawesome package) and add the css and js into your angular json. I've tested it yesterday it works without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I have this in my project.

`npm install font-awesome --save`

Add font-awesome link in `angular.json` :

```
"../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
```

Use in HTML
`<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i>`

Comment: where in the angularkson you add it?which part?

Comment: "styles": [ "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" ]. Note: this in the project section of angular.json not the test section.

Comment: i updated my question you add it under the input?i added right above the "src/styles.css" and did not work

Comment: Add this below "src/styles.css": 
`"node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"`
This should work