# Angular + FontAwesome: specify using a class

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I'm working in Angular 11 with FontAwesome, and there's a context where I'd like to specify an icon by specifying a class attribute on an html element, after the fashion of the vanilla font-awesome usage, instead of by specifying an `[icon]` attribute. Is there a good way for me to do that in Angular, though?

This doesn't produce any visible icon:

```html
<fa-icon class="fa fa-bars"></fa-icon>
```

But this does:

```html
<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'bars']"></fa-icon>
```

I'd like to specify this as a class instead of with `[icon]` because I have an `ngRepeat` in which I need to vary the icon depending on a property of the repetition's item *and* set two classes on the element, varying by that same property. Is there some approach that would be best for my needs?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796541/how-to-add-font-awesome-to-angular-2-cli-project

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `<span>`. Try this: `<span class="fa fa-bars"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

Also ensure you only run: " **npm install font-awesome** " instead of the more specific commands listed on:

https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome

You can then just import the CSS directly in the style.css file by adding this line:

**@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";**