# Installing font awesome into my angular 12 app in visual studio 2019

Tags: css, angular, visual-studio-2019, font-awesome

Can anyone give me a simple step-by-step guide on how to install font awesome (free version) in my angular 12 app in visual studio 2019?  I've googled endlessly and seen many options of differing complexity. Why on earth is there this ridiculous amount of complexity simply to use some fonts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796541/how-to-add-font-awesome-to-angular-2-cli-project

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1

In command prompt execute following command:

```
npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

### Step 2

In `styles.scss` add this line:

```css
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
```

### Step 3

Use it:

```html
<span class="fab fa-angular"></span>
```