# Not able to fetch, write and read a font file using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, nodejs-stream

**Problem** :

File downloaded using the request module, and written it to the file system is differnt to the one directly downloaded using the browser

I am fetching a font file located at `https://assets.ajio.com/static/assets/ec86819f634b9e9979b83bae65b170dd.woff`. there are the following 3 cases.

**Case 1**

Now when normally the website runs this URL from its source code, the following is the response [as checked in deveoper tools]

> d09GRgABAAAAAPqMABMAAAACNCgAAQAyAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABCQVN....

and when I fetch it using my nodejs script, I get the response

> wOFF....??....4(...2....

The above was the response I saw in browser's developer's tools network tab.

**Case 2**

But when I run both the urls i.e. the original and my own `http://<host>/_oe/https://assets.ajio.com/static/assets/ec86819f634b9e9979b83bae65b170dd.woff`, in Postman, I get the same response.

**Case 3**

Then again when copy and paste `https://assets.ajio.com/static/assets/ec86819f634b9e9979b83bae65b170dd.woff` in a broswer, the file which downloads reads like

> 774f 4646 0001 0000 0000 c7f4 000b 0000
>   0000 c7a8 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
>   0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 4f53 2f32

and the file which gets written using my nodejs script reads like

> 774f 4646 0001 0000 0000 efbf bdef bfbd
>   000b 0000 0000 c7a8 0001 0000 0000 0000
>   0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

Both are again different.

**Question**

My question is, can anyone explain whats going on here, what am I doing wrong, and what can I do to get the correct font file with correct encoding so that it is used correctly on the frontend.

**Nodejs script** :
Here's my code of nodejs

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    var extension = '.woff';
    var options         = {
        headers: {
            'connection': 'keep-alive',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
        },
        url: 'https://assets.ajio.com/static/assets/ec86819f634b9e9979b83bae65b170dd.woff'
    };

    sendRequest(options, extension, function(headers){

        //setting response headers
        var header_ = {};
        for(var attribute in  headers){
            if(attribute !== 'content-length'){
                header_[attribute] = headers[attribute];
            }
        }

        //#================================================================
        res.writeHead(200, header_);
        var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'output/temp'+extension);
            var stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath);
            var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath);
            //read from `readStream` write to `res`
            readStream.pipe(res);
        //#================================================================

    });

})

async function sendRequest(options, extension, callback){
    var headers;
    request(options, function(error, response, body){
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            headers = response.headers;

            if (String(response.headers['content-type']).indexOf('text/html') !== -1){
                // any manipulation related to the html file                
            }else {
                // where I get my font url response
                fileSystem.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, 'output/temp'+extension), body, function(err) {
                    if(err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    }
                    callback(headers);
                }); 
            }
        }
    });
}

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

**UPDATE**

I have even used "binary" option while writing file i.e.

```
fileSystem.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, 'output/temp'+extension), body, "binary", function(err) {})
```

Now on console I get data in the required format
`d09GRgABAAAAAP39AAs...`

but still different from what I get from the original website i.e.
`d09GRgABAAAAAPqMABMAAAACNC...`

Comment: Why do you think that `d09GRgABAAAAAPqMABMAA` and `wOFF....??` are different? The first one is the base64 representation of the data and often used if the content that has to be displayed is binary.

Comment: Pls read the last part of question (Update). Now I am using the binary encoding to write file and i am getting base64 representation as u suggested, but still they both are different. They both meaning one I get from my nodejs script and one I get from the original website @t.niese

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Node.js failed to serve .woff files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372997/why-node-js-failed-to-serve-woff-files)

Comment: I read the whole question. If you ask a question you should first write what problem you have. Somethign like: `File downloaded using the request module, and written it to the file system is differnt to the one directly downloaded using the browser`.  Adding those overservatiosn is great, but you should help the read to understand the problem first.

Comment: @Paul don't know about the question but the answer specified there I have already mentioned in my question that it is not working. So could be different context. Thanks

Comment: @t.niese got it. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the raw buffer for the response, you would need to set `encoding` to `null`

```
var options = {
    url: 'https://assets.ajio.com/static/assets/ec86819f634b9e9979b83bae65b170dd.woff',
    encoding : null
};
```

If you then write this to a file:

```
request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    fs.writeFile('test.woff', body, function(err) {

    })
})
```

Then this will be equl to the one you requested.